# calling this of other function using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to call below function and my expected output is "Hi John, my name is James"

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name; // not working
}
```

name is not defined in above code.

Comment: Surprisingly: `this.name`

Answer (score 2):

Use `this.name`

```js
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}

var p = new Person("Foo");
console.log(p.greet("Bar"));   // "Hi Bar, my name is Foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

to access the properties attached on the this object, well.. you have to call `this.`

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}
```